# How do I group different anagrams together from a given string array?

Tags: java, arraylist, anagram

I have a question. So lets say I have about 10 different string types, and I need to write a method where depending on if the strings are anagrams, they are grouped together. Whats the best way to approach this? 2D arrays?

I obviously have other methods that compare the strings and determine whether they are anagrams. This question is solely to ask how do I approach this problem of sorting different strings in different groups.

List example:
-Dog
-Bread
-Africa
-God
-Dreab
-dGO
-Treat
-dabre
-trate
-China

Group 1: Dog, god, dGO

Group 2: Bread, Dreab, dabre

Group 3: Africa

Group 4: Treat, trate

Group 5: China

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to create a `Map<String,List<String>>`.  All anagrams of the same letters sort to the same sorted `string`.  So that string would be your key to the map.  The `List` portion would be the actual anagrams.

so acne and cane would be

acen => [acne, cane]

To sort the anagram you need to split the string into letters and then use either `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort`.  Then put the letters back together.

Answer (score 0):

Java Code based on the above mentioned answer.

```
    Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(strs.length);
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList(strs));
    for(String str:words){
        char[] word = str.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(word);
        String sortedWord = new String(word);
        
        if(anagrams.containsKey(sortedWord)){
            anagrams.get(sortedWord).add(str);
        }
        else{
           anagrams.put(sortedWord, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str))); 
        }
        
    }
    List<List<String>> output = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry:anagrams.entrySet()){
        output.add(entry.getValue());
    }
    return output;
}
```

here anagrams will be the map which would have the key-value pair of anagram word in sorted form as key and corresponding variants of that anagram as value.